# How can I listen Tap Event outside a container in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to vanish a container whenever I tap outside the container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Visibility widget and put your containers into a stack

```
bool isVisible = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: stackedContainers()
    );
  }

  Stack stackedContainers() {
    return new Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        myContainer(),
        GestureDetector(
          child: background(),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              isVisible = false;
            });
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Container myContainer() {
    return Container(
      child: Visibility(
        visible: isVisible,
       //.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/tap_canvas

> Detect taps outside the currently defined widget and provide a
> callback when taps occur.

It has some problems with auto update at the moment (2021.01) , put it manually in a lib\something.. directory.